# Calling an API hosted by MS Azure

Tags: namedcredentials, auth-provider, azure

On the Azure Portal console we have registered an application through the App Registration page.

The app has a client credential with 1 secret.

We have created a custom scope, called custom.scope.

We defined our auth provider on Salesforce with this information; in the default scopes session we have put

api://custom.scope offline_access

[image]

we have also created a named credential based on this Auth provider; the defined url is

https://salesforce-connector-ac2g6yexdq-nw.a.run.app/api/v1/salesforce/objects

[image]

However, it seems that Salesforce is not able to generate a refresh token when the previous one is expired.

The apex code is the following. We have a trigger

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (after insert) {
 LeadClassCallout.calloutTest();
}
```

And an Apex class that calls our external endpoint

```
    public class LeadClassCallout {
    @Future(callout=true)
        public static void calloutTest() {
             HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET'); 
  
req.setEndpoint('callout:SFDC_Microsoft_Issue/0066g00003Zx42uAAB'); 
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        Http h = new Http(); 
    
        HttpResponse resp = h.send(req);
    System.debug( resp.getBody()+'===='+resp.getStatus());
    }
    }
```

When we call our external service, the service sends back a 401 error but Salesforce doesn't refresh the token. Any clue on what the issue can be?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: How did you make a decision to use `Microsoft Access Control Service` as the auth provider type?

Comment: I also tried OpenID and it doesn't change anything

Comment: While setup/config on Azure side can vary, OpenID Connect is the right auth provider type out of the box: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_provider_azure.htm&type=5 . If you've tried it, please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've updated the question with the information

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it helps. It's not clear if the 401 comes back on the very first request. If so, then your issue is not the refresh token but the authorization of your client/call. Two items to check: correct config of non-custom scopes on [Azure side](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis) and whether you've initialized the auth provider in SF. The latter can be done by hitting the OAuth Init URL shown in your screenshot. If neither step yields success, then you should open a support case with Salesforce.

Comment: Give the Summer 22 version of this a shot: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_microsoft_auth_provider.htm&type=5&release=238